# How to load a local csv text file into a local html/css/javascript file (without browse/select) after loading into a local webbrowser control

Tags: javascript, html, css, vb.net, csv

I have a vb.net app that creates a csv text file. I have a second vb.net app that loads a html/css/javascript file into a webbrowser control on my local machine. When the html/css/javascript is displayed it shows an input file request (browse/select file/OK). When I select the csv text file created by the first vb.net app, the csv data is displayed in a table that was created by the html/css/javascript code. Clicking on a button of the second vb.net app, the table is saved as an html file.

I want to be able to do the same task without the browse/select file step, i.e., load the csv file as soon as the html/css/javascript file finishes loading into the webbrowser control. There is no security issue because everything is done on the local machine. How can I do this or is it not possible

All of the many posts that I have read discuss loading from a server or a web browser on line, not a local webbrowser control.

Comment: So you've read right in all many posts. That's what needs to be done for your use case.

Comment: You can [Write()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmldocument.write) to a HtmlDocument a formated Html (read the notes there) or set the `InnerHtml` or `InnerText` properties of any existing or new [`HtmlElement`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.htmlelement) at any time. If you have a `<DIV>` placeholder, add formatted Html to its content.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I examined the HtmlDocument.Write(String) Method and the example. It adds a html document. Will that still work with trying to add a csv text file?

Comment: `Write()` works better when you provide an already formatted Html page. Otherwise, you can use the HtmlElement properties and set those. You can also add new HtmlElement objects to the Document, at any time. Maybe, as children of an existing *placeholder* Element (usually, a `<DIV>` element, because of its `block` nature and `display` destination), as already described.